# disabling logo's align left on the menu bar

Tags: php, html, css, menu, alignment

I'm creating a website. and I'm starting with the header first. 
I have this code for my header page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Responsive Navigation Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var pull        = $('#pull');
                menu        = $('nav ul');
                menuHeight  = menu.height();

            $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                menu.slideToggle();
            });

            $(window).resize(function(){
                var w = $(window).width();
                if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                    menu.removeAttr('style');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="index.php">
<img border="0" class="logo" src="images/logo.png" width="15%" height="20%" align="left" /></a> <font size="15%"><div align="center" class="BDtext"> Title Here<br> Description Here</font></div><br>
    <nav class="clearfix">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li class="home"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li class="about"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
            <li class="me"><a href="ben.php">About Me</a></li>
            <li class="sessions"><a href="sessions.php">Sessions</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Which I am aware that the `align="left"` is used to allow everything else to be positioned to the right of image.

however.

I only want the title and description to be to the right of the image.

in some web browsers, the menu bar goes over the image.

*an example of this is when I use this code in my style.css:*

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

.BDtext {
display: none;
}
```

I want this to be aligned underneath the image.

Please can someone explain how I can keep the image aligned left but stop the menu bar from overlapping the image instead of using the br code?

please help.

thank you.

Comment: I think it would be better to put the `<img>` inside a stand alone `<div>`, this one containing the `align="left"`

Comment: the `align` attribute is deprecated in HTML5. I think you are searching for `float: left;` from CSS. Put your declarations inside of your `style.css` and do not write it inline (directly in your HTML)

Comment: @fedorqui your suggestion does not work.

Comment: @Nico O this is the same as before right? this does not stop my menu overlapping the logo. will a css position sort this? if so which one?

Comment: Here is some of your HTML cleaned up with some sample css. You will have to learn to style your page with CSS: http://fiddle.jshell.net/KxC8S/

Comment: @Nico O please have a look at my post again. I have added more info. I'm not sure you understand what I mean.

Comment: However, do Not use the align attribute. Make the image float:left; and add `clear:left` Inside of your Media query